# No application images / icons displaying on phonegap desktop app

Tags: phonegap-desktop-app

After every fresh install of phonegap v0.2.1 on windows 7 I see no application images within the app itself. Is there any way to fix this?

example :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems, that this is related to having installed an development version of Inkscape. The development version places incorrect values into the registry preventing Phonegap from correctly loading the SVG icons.

Issue on Phonegap: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/309

Related issue with detailed description: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/7208#issuecomment-37914802

**Solution 1:** Replace Inkscape with a stable version.

**Solution 2:**

1. Open Start menu, type regedit.exe and open it.
2. Search for "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.svg"
3. Change "(Default)" value to "svgfile" (without quotes)
4. Change "Content Type" to "image/svg+xml" (without quotes)
5. Close Registry editor
6. Open Phonegap

Comment: Fantastic, I have never heard of Inkscape before, so I attempted Solution 2 but the registry key did not exist. So I installed the latest version of Inkscape and I assume the correct registry entries were entered. It works now. Thank you kindly Alex.